# How to get css and scripts with loaded contents via ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

i have an index page that contain div content. i load contents from other divs in other pages via ajax inside index page content div. the content successfully loaded but without its css and scripts. How can i load the content with its css and scripts to work inside content div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".menuAnchor").click(function (event) {            
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).attr('title ');
        window.history.pushState("",title,url);
        $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
            $(".contn_btm_mid_bg").html($(data).find('.contn_btm_mid_bg').html());
            //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(".contn_btm_mid_bg");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ok do one thing load your css and js externally using code

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "/styles/yourcss.css"
}).appendTo("head");
```

same for js

Answer (score 0):

either declare css on index page or declare css within div on other page(ajax page)

Comment: i try that but the result the same content without css and scripts

Answer (score 0):

Put Css and Js inside target `div` which you want to load.

Comment: also the result the same content without css and scripts

Comment: in your console what is `data` ?? does it include css and scripts orr do alert(data) to see your result..!!